# Http POST request of json data and null values

Tags: json, http

what is the difference in a json request I make wrt to a field 'a' for a POST

```
[{"a",}, // Here I don't specifiy a value for a, Is this treated as null ? 
 {"a":1},// Here I specify a value for a which is 1
 {"a",""} // Here I specify 
 {}] // ?
```

When is the value for 'a' treated as null ?

Answer (score 3):

According to the JSON specification, (http://json.org/) JSON objects `{ ... }` must contain key value pairs in the form of a string key followed a colon separator and any json value including null. Your sample JSON is not valid JSON because:

`{"a",}` The "a" is a valid key but is not followed by a colon and value. The comma is also not followed by anything which is invalid json.

`{"a",""}` Again, the "a" is not followed by a colon and value. `""` is a valid key but it, too, is not followed by a colon and value

In summary, valid json always has an explicit value: `{ "a" : null }` is therefore the only way to get `null` as a value for the key `"a"`

Comment: what if the key wasn't passed in at all ? would that be treated as null ?

Comment: non-existent keys in json objects have no defined value in the json specification. It would be up to the software reading the json to determine what it means in context. A missing key, for example, could be an error if the software reading it requires it's presence. It could be interpreted as a null value in other cases, or as simply omitted as in the context of a partial REST update (PATCH).